# compound tags in a css element

Tags: html, css

So in an attempt too work on some of my css elements, I've been trying to extend color to my heading tags using classes with little to no success. It was fine when I had just the  tag being included in the css, but now that I am trying to open it up to the other's I am finding that I get a couple hazards on the css size, and when the text goes to display it shows up as the standard black.

Css Hazard includes: Heading (h1) should not be qualified along with Heading (h1-h6) is already defined. Thank you for any insight you can shed. Not sure why I am having these issues.

```
.bd-callout {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left-width: .25rem;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.bd-callout-info {
    border-left-color: #5bc0de;
}

.bd-callout-info h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #5bc0de;
}

.bd-callout-primary {
    border-left-color: #007bff;
}

.bd-callout-primary h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #007bff;
}

.bd-callout-secondary {
    border-left-color: #6c757d;
}

.bd-callout-secondary h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #6c757d;
}

.bd-callout-success {
    border-left-color: #75ac97;
}

.bd-callout-success h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #75ac97;
}

.bd-callout-danger {
    border-left-color: #e04e39;
}

.bd-callout-danger h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #e04e39;
}

.bd-callout-warning {
    border-left-color: #85b8c3;
}

.bd-callout-warning h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #85b8c3;
}

.bd-callout-light {
    border-left-color: #dce3e7;
}

.bd-callout-light h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #dce3e7;
}

.bd-callout-dark {
    border-left-color: #40474f;
}

.bd-callout-dark h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #40474f;
}
```

Comment: Please include the markup you're using with this. Also include what was working before.

Comment: "*Heading (h1) should not be qualified along with Heading (h1-h6) is already defined.*" - what does this mean?

Comment: You override evry time the heading from h2 to h6. so the last color for this heading is #40474f;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the class name every time:

```
.bd-callout-info h1,
.bd-callout-info h2,
.bd-callout-info h3,
.bd-callout-info h4,
.bd-callout-info h5,
.bd-callout-info h6 {
color: #5bc0de;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to do the trick, I am a bit out of practice when it comes to css, so this was a big help.